# Data is not populating in dropdown using angular?

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-material

I have datatable which will show the elements with edit button also top of the page i have add button .

Add is for adding elements into list edit is for editing the particular  row data

when user click add button one popup will come with two dropdownlist 
 Element Name and  Element symbol
here based on Element Name selection Element symbol list will come.

My expectation >

when i click first row edit button(which means Hydrogen  H )  same popup should open and we need to populate these Hydrogen(Element Name) and H(Element symbol) in dropdown like this

when i click 2nd row edit buttin (Hydrogen ,H1) it should populate these data

here is my Dialogue html

```
<h1 mat-dialog-title>{{data.element.ModalName.name}}  </h1>
<form  [formGroup]="addTaskForm"  (ngSubmit)="save()" >
<mat-form-field>
  <mat-select formControlName="name" placeholder="Element Name"
  (selectionChange)="elementSelectionChange($event)">
    <mat-option *ngFor="let element of Elements" [value]="element.name">
      {{ element.name }}
    </mat-option>
  </mat-select>
</mat-form-field>
<mat-form-field>
  <mat-select  formControlName="symbol"  placeholder="Element symbol">
    <mat-option *ngFor="let element of selectedElementSymbols" [value]="element.symbol">
      {{ element.symbol }}
    </mat-option>
  </mat-select>
</mat-form-field>

<div mat-dialog-actions>

  <button mat-button (click)="onNoClick()">Cancel</button>
<button type="submit"  mat-button cdkFocusInitial>{{data.element.ModalName.button}}</button>



</div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-talrct-prnwvr

In above template I basically made two changes one on line 27 commented re initialization of element and in constructor to update list of symbols based on selection.

Comment: Edit functionality working but when i click add that time not working . it should work both add and edit

Answer (score 0):

You need to add `(click)="onEditClick()"` event to HTML of your popup button. Then in TS file add `onEditClick(){}` and there you can catch data you have chosen in dropdowns

Comment: your code is working fine. When you click "edit" button you get `Object { name: "Hydrogen", symbol: "H4" }` in console.

Comment: you need to bind data from table to two drop downs.

Answer (score 0):

store the selected table value to a variable like public

selected2 = this.options2[1].id ...

and bind with mat-option

```
<mat-select [(ngModel)]="selected2">
    <mat-option *ngFor="let option of options2" [value]="option.id">{{ 
    option.name }}</mat-option>
  </mat-select>
```